# Crud para objetos dentro de arreglos, Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

soy nuevo en esto de Node.js y MongoDb.
Tengo un esquema para proyectos el  cual tiene un arreglo de objetos

```
archivos:[{ nombre: {type:String, required:true},
    fechaCreacion: {type:String, required:false},
    fechaModificado: {type:String, required:false, default: fecha},
    responsable: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,required:true, ref:'usuarios'}}]
```

Al momento de subir un archivo nuevo quiero verificar si no existe dentro de un objeto comparando el nombre, pero dado que no tengo el id del objeto, no puedo utilizar un findById para el archivo.
 Proyecto.findById() me devuelve lo siguiente

```
{
"ok": true,
"mensaje": "Proyecto encontrado",
"proyectoActual": {
    "fechaCreacion": "Sunday, March 3rd 2019, 8:42:01 am",
    "participantes": [],
    "_id": "5c7bf5d6870d3c17b436c242",
    "nombre": "Sitio web chido",
    "descripcion": "Proyecto de Sitio progeasdasd",
    "fechaProyectada": "26/01/2020",
    "nombreEmpresa": "Dinamycs",
    "responsable": "5c7b214ad4d5b8203c046f01",
    "ultimoEditor": "5c7b214ad4d5b8203c046f01",
    "__v": 9,
    "archivos": [
        {
            "fechaModificado": "121/1354",
            "_id": "5c7bf5d6870d3c17b436c248",
            "nombre": "archivox.txt",
            "fechaCreacion": "23/456"
        }
        {
            "fechaModificado": "121/1354",
            "_id": "5c7bf5d6870d3c17b436c248",
            "nombre": "plantilla.pdf",
            "fechaCreacion": "23/456"
        }
    ]
}}
```

Teniendo esa data, quiero encontrar el objeto con nombre planitlla.pdf, compararlo con el nombre del archivo a subir y hacer update si existe, si no crear uno nuevo.
Mi duda es, cómo se puede recorrer el arreglo y buscar el nombre dentro de los objetos?

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

Si mal no entiendo tu pregunta, deseas obtener el valor de la clave `nombre` de cada objeto en el array `archivos`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para lograr lo que te propones puedes usar un bucle [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of) para recorrer cada item del array, o mejor usar el método [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach).

Una implementación de lo que deseas es la siguiente:

```js
// USANDO ES6
//
// supongamos que obj es el resultado de findById()
const obj = {
  "ok": true,
  "mensaje": "Proyecto encontrado",
  "proyectoActual": {
    "fechaCreacion": "Sunday, March 3rd 2019, 8:42:01 am",
    "participantes": [],
    "_id": "5c7bf5d6870d3c17b436c242",
    "nombre": "Sitio web chido",
    "descripcion": "Proyecto de Sitio progeasdasd",
    "fechaProyectada": "26/01/2020",
    "nombreEmpresa": "Dinamycs",
    "responsable": "5c7b214ad4d5b8203c046f01",
    "ultimoEditor": "5c7b214ad4d5b8203c046f01",
    "__v": 9,
    "archivos": [
      {
        "fechaModificado": "121/1354",
        "_id": "5c7bf5d6870d3c17b436c248",
        "nombre": "archivox.txt",
        "fechaCreacion": "23/456"
      },
      {
        "fechaModificado": "121/1354",
        "_id": "5c7bf5d6870d3c17b436c248",
        "nombre": "plantilla.pdf",
        "fechaCreacion": "23/456"
      }
    ]
  }
}

// Si la estructura es conocida, es fácil instanciar el array
const archivos = obj.proyectoActual.archivos;

//usamos el método forEach()
console.log('Usando forEach()');
console.log('================')
archivos.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item.nombre);
});
console.log('');

//usamos un bucle for...of
console.log('Usando for...of');
console.log('===============')
for (let item of archivos) {
  console.log(item.nombre);
}
```

Espero que esto sea lo que estás buscando, como verás es muy sencillo una vez que sabemos lo que necesitamos iterar.